# Autoencoder Failing to Capture Small Artifacts

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

**tl;dr - I use an autoencoder to try to reduce input dimensions for a reinforcement-learning (RL) agent to learn how to play Atari-KungFu.  But it fails at encoding/decoding thrown knives, because they are only a couple pixels and getting them wrong probably has negligible impact on the autoencoder MSE loss (see green arrows in bottom left of image).  This will probably permanently hobble the results.   I want to figure out if there is a way to solve this -- preferably with a generalized solution, but I'd be happy for now with something specific to this problem.**

---

Background:
I am working on Week5 of the "Practical Reinforcement Learning" course on Coursera (National Research University HSE), and I decided to spend extra time trying to expand performance on the Atari-KungFu assignment using Actor-Critic architecture.  This post is not about actor-critic, but more about an interesting sub-problem I ran into related to autoencoders.

I create an encoder which outputs a tanh-64-neuron layer, which is used as  a common input to the decoder, policy learner (actor), and value learner (critic).  During training, the simulator returns batches of four sequential frames (64 x 144 x 4) and rewards from the last action.  Then images are first used to train the autoencoder, then used with the rewards to train the actor & critic branches.

I display some metrics and example frames every 25000 iterations to see how it's doing.  If the reconstructed images are accurate, then the inputs to the actor & critic branches should be getting good distilled information for efficient learning.

You can see below that the autoencoder is pretty good **except** for the thrown knives (see bottom-left).  Arguably this is because missing those couple pixels minimally increases the MSE loss of the reconstructed image, so it has little incentive to learn it (and also there's not a lot of frames that have knives).  Yet, seeing those knives is critical for the RL agent to learn to how to survive.

I haven't seen this kind of problem addressed before.  A tiny artifact in the input images is crucial for learning, but is unlikely to be learned by the autoencoder.  Can we fix/improve this?

[image: See the autoencoder failing to capture knives in the bottom left]

Comment: This is pretty broad, but cool project. One thing that comes to mind is adding skip connections to your autoencoder. I'm not real familiar with whether this negates other advantages of AEs, but basically `add` the hidden layer output for some of your earlier encoder layers (which encode finer resolution features) to the hidden layer output of the same-sized (later) decoder layers. Might help.

Comment: Follow-up, my skip connection idea will give an information channel through the compressed latent space, which isn't great if you are trying to learn a compressed representation, *but* you may be able to train with these skip connections and then see how the AE performs without them. They might give you the boost you need to learn these finer-resolution features in training so that you can reconstruct without skip connections later. I'm not really sure, just spitballing.

Comment: @Engineero : That's an interesting idea, especially because I'm not tied to architecture and I don't require a pure latent space representation.  I might try adding skip connections to all three output branches (decoder, actor, critic), so that all outputs get access to both the latent space and some of the finer-detail features as you suggested.  That also checks the box for "generalized solution", since it's not specific to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

IMO your problem is loss specific, some things which would probably help autoencoder reconstruct knife as well:

- Find knives in input image using image processing techniques. Regions where knives are present should have higher loss value in MSE, say `10` times more. One way to find those semi-automatically could probably be convolution with big kernel; White pixels at the strict center would give more weight and only zeros around it would give it more weight as well. Something along these lines should find a region where only knives are located (throwing guys wouldn't, as they contain too many white pixels and holes). Using some threshold found empirically for the value of this kernel should be enough to correctly find them.
- Lower loss for images when no knive was found, say divided by half. This would focus autoencoder harder on rarely seen cases when knive is seen.

On the downside - I suppose it could introduce some artifacts. In such case you may think about usage of pretrained encoder (like some version of ResNet) and increase model's capabilities.

Comment: This solution is obviously very specific to the atari-kungfu problem, but I might try it anyway just because I want to have a version that plays really well (while I continue trying to find an agnostic solution).  Additionally, this actually has a chance of working because of the limited set of visual shapes, it's probably not much work to reliably detect knives with pre-processing and add features to the pipeline.

Comment: It is kind of agnostic as the point is to detect small objects which are underplayed by loss. Good luck

Comment: By "agnostic" I was referring to the "generality" goal, which is to able to learn the game without any feature extraction specific to this environment.  Obviously a 7-binary-pixel knife detector would only be applicable to this game.  I still want to try it, though.